# Static content doesn't update until project restart - Spring Boot & Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot project with a few html pages. Whenever I used to modify the html pages in Eclipse, the changes would take effect immediately upon refresh. Now the changes don't come into effect until I restart the whole Spring Boot project. This is making UI changes an absolute nightmare and is a big waste of time.

What is causing the html pages to no longer update upon browser refresh?

I'm using Eclipse, Tomcat, and Spring Boot.

Comment: You might accidentally uncheck autobuild option in eclipse.Please follow the link http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_autobuild.htm.
Also try sprint-boot-devtools(http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) it's an awesome tool that will publish automatically even you did changes in java or property files.

Comment: Not sure about Eclipse but in IntelliJ you have to a "build" command and then the pages are pushed out and you don't have to restart the application.   Maybe you can try that.

Comment: @VelNaga I'll look into that. I'm just confused as to why it was working before, but now it's not working.

Comment: @RobBaily In Eclipse, you just have to refresh the browser and it should update any changes.

Comment: @JakeMiller Could you please share your project structure.

Comment: @JakeMiller also please make sure you have the following option enabled Project -> "Build Automatically" in Eclipse

Comment: Hot swapping is possible in spring-boot.Most of the IDE's support hot swapping provided your files should be in a classpath. Check whether the html file is in a class path.

Answer (score 1):

Add the dependancy in pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your server configured in Eclipse? If so, go to settings and check 'Publishing', change to 'Automatically publish when resources change'

Comment: @Stugal..It's a spring-boot project by default it contains tomcat.No need of external tomcat server

Comment: Ups, missed that, maybe it has something similar though?